# Timezone problems with MongoDB and NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So the problem I'm currently having is :

I've a list of gym classes, which every class has an OpeningTime. I want to fetch all the classes from the current day, but. I'm not getting the same result locally and in production, cause for some reason, when Im deploying my backend to Heroku, the timezone is being setted by default to UTC (when I've a GMT-3 timezone).

Here is my query :

```
 var now = moment();

 var startOfDay = now.startOf('day').format();

 var endOfDay = now.endOf('day').format();

 var clasesDB = await Clase.find({ $and: [{ openingTime: { $gte: startOfDay } }, { openingTime: { $lte: endOfDay } }] })
```

So, like I said before, the problem is ocurring when, for example:

When I fetch the classes at my local time (Ex: 02-26-19 21:00hs ( GMT-3) ), the queries are actually showing the classes from **02-27**, because, at MINE 21:00hs, on the server side is already 00:00, so, the date is not **02-26** anymore. And I dont want this kind of output.

How can I get a workaround to solve this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: have you tried normalizing your client query to account for the fact that its time-zone is diff ( minus 3 ) , then passing the delta hours to the server api where u accept the parm ( hours + or - ) and pass that into your function making the DB call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.format()`, this makes a **string**. Compare directly `Date` values, i.e. use

```
var now = moment();

var startOfDay = now.startOf('day').toDate();    
var endOfDay = now.endOf('day').toDate();
```

By default `moment` uses local times, so `moment().startOf('day')` returns midnight of local time. If you want to get midnight of UTC then use `moment.utc().startOf('day')`.

If you don't rely on "local" time zone, then you can specify it like `moment.tz("America/New_York").startOf('day')`

No matter which time you need, **never** compare Date values by string, use always actual `Date` value.

Answer (score 1):

By default in MongoDB a date field is stored in **UTC**, You can create a date with offset while writing to store it in your timeZone. But you've not done it while writing documents then you need to convert date field to your required timeZone while reading data from database. Check this below example.

**JavaScript Code :**

```
const today = new Date().toLocaleDateString(undefined, {
    day: '2-digit',
    month: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric'
})  // 02/26/2020. If your Heroic server is in different location then specify your locale in place of undefined - whereas undefined picks local time by default. Ex:- 'en-Us' for USA
```

**Query :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { timewithOffsetNY: { $dateToString: { format: "%m/%d/%Y", date: "$openingTime", timezone: "America/New_York" } } } },
    { $match: { timewithOffsetNY: today } }, { $project: { timewithOffsetNY: 0 } }
])
```

Above query is written for New York timeZone, you can convert it according to your timeZone, In test url you can see 1st doc is not returned though it is on `2020-02-26` cause offset to New York as of today is 5hrs, So after converting date becomes as `2020-02-25`.

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2wk5LCh9G1Z)

**Ref :** [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html)